# Удалить все копии элемента в списке, кроме последнего вхождения

Tags: c++

Как удалить все копии элементов в списке, кроме их последнего вхождения? Код ниже работает частично - только для одной копии элемента. Но если элемент стоит в начале или повторяется больше 2-х раз, то выдаёт разные ошибки.

Ожидаемы результат для списка **2 3 3 2 4 5 6 5** -> **3 2 4 6 5**. Но при попытке выполнить получаем: `Вызвано исключение: нарушение доступа для чтения. cur было 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF7.` на строку `for (List* cur(head); cur && cur->next; cur = cur->next) {`

Пример 1: Есть список **2 3 4 5 3**. После выполнения станет правильным -> **2 4 5 3**

Пример 2: Иной список **3 2 4 5 3**. После выполнения пишет, что удалён 1 элемент, но после попытки вывода возникает ошибка `Вызвано исключение: нарушение доступа для чтения. p было 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.` На строку **printf("%d ", p->value);**

Пример 3: Список с большим повторением **2 3 4 3 5 3**. После выполнения пишет, что удалено 2 элемента, но выводится **2 4 5**

Мне кажется, что ошибка в переданном `head` для функции `Delete_copy`, но как её разрешить не знаю.

```
struct List{
    int value; 
    List* next; 
    List(int val = 0, List* p = NULL) {
        value = val;
        next = p;
    }
};
List* Insert_first(int n, List* head){
    List* q = new List(n, head);
    return q;
}
List* Delete_value(int n, List* head)
{
    List* p = head, * t;
    if (head == NULL) { puts("LIST EMPTY!"); return NULL; }
    if (head->value == n)
    {
        t = head;
        head = head->next;
        delete t;
        return head;
    }
    while (p->next != NULL)
        if (p->next->value == n)
        {
            t = p->next;
            p->next = p->next->next;
            delete t;
            return head;
        }
        else p = p->next;
    puts("NO VALUE!");
    return head;
}
void Print_list(List* head){
    List* p = head;
    puts("\n PRINT LIST");
    if (p == NULL) puts("List empty!");
    else
        while (p != NULL){
            printf("%d ", p->value);
            p = p->next;
        }
}
int Delete_copy(int countRes, List * head) {
    std::vector<int> v;
    v.push_back(head->value);
    for (List* cur(head); cur && cur->next; cur = cur->next) {
        if ((std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), cur->next->value) != v.end()) && cur->next) {
            head = Delete_value(cur->next->value, head);
            countRes++;
            Delete_copy(countRes, head);
        }
        else {
            if (cur->next){
                v.push_back(cur->next->value);
            }
            else {
                return countRes;
            }
        }
    }
    return countRes;
}
void main()
{
    int i, k, n, num;
    char const * ss[] = { "\n 0-Print list"," 1-Insert first", " 2-Delete copy"," 3-EXIT" };
    char c{};
    List* head = NULL;
    k = sizeof(ss) / sizeof(ss[0]);
    for (;;){
        for (i = 0; i < k; i++) puts(ss[i]);
        scanf_s("%c", &c); 
        switch (c){
        case '0': Print_list(head);    break;
        case '1': printf("n = "); scanf_s("%d", &num); head = Insert_first(num, head);    break;
        case '2': printf("Was delete %d elemens", Delete_copy(0, head)); break;
        case '3': return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: В функции `Delete_copy` не учитывается удаление элемента, первого в списке. Нужно передавать указатель на `head` ссылкой `List * & head`. *желательно код давать компилируемый. покажите функцию **Delete_value***

Comment: @AlexGlebe Добавил

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Так платформа и создана, чтобы решать проблемы и искать более удачные подходы

Comment: @Pashok, вы называете списком структуру,  которая может служить только как один узел списка, потому не удивительно, что вы считаете  SO местом для разбора и отладки  любого кода, который вы напишете. Тут место для ответов на **конкретный вопрос**, а  не решают все ваши проблемы по всему коду.  Я  просто  изложил свое мнение, и  целый лист статьи не собираюсь писать, чтобы потом еще и отвечать на десятки вопросов. Я не отрицаю, что может кто нибудь другой поможет вам

Comment: @ARHovsepyan *Конкретный вопрос:* Как удалить все копии элементов в списке, кроме их последнего вхождения? Проблема-то одна, ошибки разные, которые приведены. Но я Вас понял

Comment: @Pashok, №1 вы пытаетесь реализовывать функцию для интрузивного списка, но пользуетесь не интрузивным  std::vector<int>.   Тогда зачем вам сразу не пользоваться  std::list<int>, который имеет  методы и сортировки и слияния?..   Ответ зависит еще и от  подобных факторов.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan я согласен, что через std::list всё делается, буквально в несколько строк, но мне была поставлена задача через свою структуру List сделать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кое-как, но нашёл такое решение. Если есть идеи по оптимизации, то буду благодарен (Можно динамически задавать массивы). Функция `Delete_value` из вопроса не менялась

```
List* Delete_copy(int countRes, List * &head) {
    List* p, * q, * def;
    p = head;
    q = head;
    def = head;
    int keys[10];
    int values[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        keys[i] = 0;
        values[i] = 0;
    }
    int arr_length = 0;
    while (p != NULL) {
        int index = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            if (keys[i] == p->value) {
                values[i]++;
                index = 0;
                break;
            }
            else {
                index++;
            }
        }
        if (index == 0) {
            p = p->next;
            continue;
        }
        else {
            if (arr_length < 10) {
                keys[arr_length] = p->value;
                values[arr_length]++;
                arr_length++;
            }
        }

        p = p->next;
    }
    int counter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            if (values[i] > 1) {
                for (int countCopy = 0; countCopy < values[i]-1; countCopy++) {
                    def = Delete_value(keys[i], def);
                    counter++;
                }
            }
        }
    printf("Was delete %d elemens", counter);
    return def;
}
```

И в менюшке

```
case '2': head = Delete_copy(0, head); break;
```